# Why doesn't this simple imageMagick command from the docs work?

Tags: windows, command-line, imagemagick

```
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16>convert dragon.gif'[64x64]' read_dragon.gif
convert.exe: unable to open image `dragon.gif'[64x64]'': No such file or directo
ry @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert.exe: unable to open module file `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\
modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_GIF'[64X64]'_.dll': No such file or directory @ warning
/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/683.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `dragon.gif'[64x64]'' @ er
ror/constitute.c/ReadImage/550.
convert.exe: no images defined `read_dragon.gif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageC
ommand/3078.
```

However the following works without a problem:

```
convert dragon.gif dragon.png
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Post this as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a regular Unix shell, the single quotes would be parsed away by the shell. I'm not sure the Windows shell does this. Does this work?

```
convert dragon.gif[64x64] read_dragon.gif
```

Or this?

```
convert "dragon.gif[64x64]" read_dragon.gif
```